# iPhone does not recognize PhoneGap's navigator.app

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova

I have a button to exit from the application. The function looks like this:

```
//Close application
function close_window() {
  navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

It did not work, so I tried the following line:

```
navigator.device.exitApp();
```

It did not work either. Then I discovered by alert that the iPhone does not recognize PhoneGap's navigator.app and navigator.device. I use PhoneGap version 2.2.0.

Why is this happening?

P.S.: It works for me on Android.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**navigator.app.exitApp()** does not work on IOS, only Android. On iOS, Apple does not allow apps to programmatically exit.

It can be done through iOS objective c side but there's a good chance this app will be rejected in Apple app store.

Here you will find a good explanation: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/XjTm0ua4uOY.