# PhoneGap ask if you want to exit or go back history

Tags: android, cordova, back-button

this is my code:

```
   function onLoad(){
                alert("onLoad");
                document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, true);
             }

             function onDeviceReady(){
                navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working!!");
                document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
             }


            function onBackKeyDown(e) {        
                    navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap handle back button click!!!");
                     /* want you to go back???
                          if yes go back or exit app
                     */
            }
```

Can you help me to do

```
/* want you to go back???

   if yes go back or exit app

*/
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use use onBackPressed instead if you wanna handle the back button.from the main class.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showAlert() {
                    navigator.notification.confirm(
                        'Vuoi uscire dall\'applicazione?',  // message
                        onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
                        'Chiudere?',            // title
                        'Chiudi app,Annulla'          // buttonLabels
                    );
                }

            function onConfirm(button) {
                if(button==1)           
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

navigator.app.exitApp() doesn't work on iOS :(

hier:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423091/826822