# To close ios app phonegap jquery mobile if no internet connection

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

To close ios app  phonegap jquery mobile if no internet connection for android:

```
function onDeviceOffline()   {
    var internet_status = navigator.onLine;
    if (internet_status == false) { 
        navigator.notification.confirm('Do you Want to exit from App?', 
            function confirmcCallback(buttonIndex) {
                if(buttonIndex == 1)
                {
                    navigator.app.exitApp();               
                }
            }, 'Chere Weddings', 'OK,Cancel');
    }
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceOffline, false);
```

but it's not working in ios, how to work with ios?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What's the part of the code that is not working? Do you see the confirm msg? Do you get the `navigator.onLine` flag set on iOS? I would start by checking that I have the required plugins configured in config.xml for iOS.

Comment: navigator.app.exitApp();  is not working , it's not exit from app

Comment: if you force close the app in iOS, appstore will reject it..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422908/iphone-does-not-recognize-phonegaps-navigator-app